# How to put a widget in a tab in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm currently working on a security camera project. It has mainly two functions:

1. Catches the videoframes with faces
2. Shows the captured frames

I succesfully wrote the code for both classes but a problem occurs when I try to put 2nd function

```
class Iwindow(QMainWindow, gui):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.cntr, self.numImages = -1, -1  # self.cntr have the info of which image is selected/displayed
    self.image_viewer = ImageViewer(self.label)
    self.showMaximized()
    self.selectFolder.clicked.connect(self.selectDir)
    self.nextImage.clicked.connect(self.nextImg)
    self.prevImage.clicked.connect(self.prevImg)
    self.listView.clicked.connect(self.item_click)
```

This is from the code for image displaying. When I try to put image viewer to a tab widget in another program it doesn't go under the tab when I try to do it.

```
#Create second tab
    self.tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.imgViewWidget = Iwindow()
    self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.imgViewWidget)
    self.tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
```

this is when I try to call widget.
Could anyone help me?

this is the final product of my code

[image]

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Comment: Try looking into this [this](https://pythonbasics.org/pyqt-tabwidget/)

Comment: It seems you are adding items in the second tab, but you'll not be able to check that if you dont set the focus to that tab (Tab2) with: self.tab2.setCurrentIndex(index). For your case self.tab2.setCurrentIndex(1). (0 for the first tab, 1 for the seecond)

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to set the layout of `self.tab2`, `self.tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)` should be `self.tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.tab2)`. Also, the second assignment to `self.tab2.layout` will create a new empty layout.